# sessionId to spring security UserDetails

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.1.4 and I'm trying to find a solution for the next problem: I have sessionId and I want to get the UserDetails from a session.

I **cant** use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use SecurityContextHolder? Do you have the sessionId or do you have the HttpSession object?

Comment: I cant use SecurityContextHolder because I'm out of session and i have the session id.